# How to scale image block using only css?

Tags: html, css, scale

*Here is 3 inline blocks. The first one is scalable and the right two blocks has fixed width.
In case we resize browser right to block should be visible anyway. #blockID should fit the page, at the same time image should be scalable if we resized window.*

I'm trying to make image in first block scalable.

I found several ways to do that using JS, but JS is not suitable because of  discreteness. Is there some tricks to do that using only css?

Here is my code (http://jsfiddle.net/t69f60s6/):

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 300px; white-space: nowrap;" id="blockID">

        <div style="max-width: 640;">
            <div style="display: inline-block; height: 300px;  max-width: 300px; width: 100%; background: #ffff00; position: relative; overflow: hidden;" id="pano">
                <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8697/17332403271_4122fda0b8_h.jpg" style=" top:0; left:0; width:100%;  min-width: 100%;  max-width: 100%; position: absolute; "/>
            </div>

            <div style="display: inline-block; height: 300px; width: 640px; background: #000;">

            </div>

            <div style="display: inline-block; height: 300px; width: 60px; background: #ff7870;">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**UPDATE 1:**
I have changed the cursive text

**UPDATE 2:**
I can achieve this effect using table css. But table is not good.
http://jsfiddle.net/6ng62eb7/4/

Comment: "*The first one is scalable and the left one are fixed*", the first one **is** the left... You probably mean that the right two are fixed...? Please clarify.

Comment: Here the "Left" is a verb - "leave" in the past.

Comment: Can you explain a bit better? You want to make the image scale with respect to what? Make it big enough that the 3 inline-blocks just fill the window width, regardless of how big it is, or something else?

Comment: @Florian Rivoal - here is what I would like to get using display:inline or float - http://jsfiddle.net/6ng62eb7/4/ Try to resize window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to combine display-block and inline-block like here:

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 300px; white-space: nowrap;">
    <div style="width: 100%; min-width: 641px; ">
        <div style="display: table-cell; width: 30%; height: 286px; background: #ffff00; max-width: 350px; vertical-align: top;" id="pano">
            <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8697/17332403271_4122fda0b8_h.jpg" style=" max-width: 90%; margin: 5%; " />
        </div>

        <div style="display: table-cell; width: 70%; min-width: 641px;">

            <div style="display: inline-block; width: 641px; height: 286px; background: #000;" id="content">

            </div>

            <div style="display: inline-block; width: 60px; height: 286px; background: #0044ff;" id="basket">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rfh8dgqu/

I'm not sure about cross-browser compatible but it works in chrome

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the image only a max-width of 100%.

So change:

```
<img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8697/17332403271_4122fda0b8_h.jpg" style=" top:0; left:0; width:100%;  min-width: 100%;  max-width: 100%; position: absolute; "/>
```

to:

```
<img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8697/17332403271_4122fda0b8_h.jpg" style="max-width: 100%;"/>
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t69f60s6/1/)

Comment: In this case  it scalable after the right blocks are already out of browser . Right blocks should be visible

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the image a `max-width: 100%` . This will scale the image in regards to it's container. Then you need to scale the container the image is in. For now you have set `<div style="max-width: 300px; width: 100%;" id="pano">` for the parent div, so the img inside will only total to 300px at max.

You also have the overall container set to `<div style="max-width: 640px;">`, which means that all 3 of your elements together will never be bigger than 640 px.

This is why you only see your image scaling when you make the browser window smaller.

Bottom line is, you have to make the whole element (including its container responsive or this won't work) - you have to use % instead of px, em... when defining box size. This also means the other two elements you want to keep to the right have to be in % (and all 3 need to add up to 100%.)

Comment: Yes, you are right - I all 3 elements together never be bigger than 640px. The main aim  is to hide image if we have small window (less then 900px) at the same time image should be bigger then 300px but it could be 200px or 100px in width.

Comment: for this you need something called media queries. Typically you'd write something like `@media screen and (min-width:900px) { body { background-color: #000; } }` into your css file (this changes body background to black if the screen is larger than 900px).

Comment: I updated post. There an example effect what I need. I could use table-cell css but it does not work in ie7.

Comment: what you posted doesn't make an image responsive, it just hides it when your screen is larger than 751px. You do not need cells for this, you can just target the image directly using a selector such as a class or id

Comment: Image is responsive there. Try to resize window here http://jsfiddle.net/6ng62eb7/4/

Comment: use `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: table-cell` . For some reason this messes with the first div positioning, but I can't really figure out why.

Comment: ok. I think I will use combination of table-cell and inline-block. I don't know another way.